# What is the term for metaphorical definitions of words?

Tags: phrase-requests

In the medieval period when students were being taught languages like Latin or concepts in metaphysics, etc, often the education would take place as a *[catechism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechism)* involving pat questions and answers. In some cases these would be colorful similes. For example:

Teacher:
  Quid est "suere"? (What is "suere"? [to sew])

Student:
  Acus filum tractat. (A needle pulling thread.)

So, when we have poetic question-and-answer similes as a *definition*, as above, what is this called in English?

Comment: Do-Re-Mi -- https://youtu.be/drnBMAEA3AM

Comment: I don't see any metaphor or simile. The Q&A in the example seems to be pretty literal.

Comment: "Catechism", which you use, seems the best term for such call-and-response, which uses pat phrases but no particular metaphor. Can you maybe explain a bit more, perhaps provide examples of things you think meet your definition and don't meet it?

Comment: Grammar (Latin grammar, natch) used to be taught [this way](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html) (and English grammar still is, if the questions we get here are any example). _Catechism_ is definitely the right word. There are standard questions and there are standard answers, the lot to be memorized and recited on command.

Comment: In crossword solving, they are termed 'loose definitions' (as loose as the compiler dare include). Here, your example is not as loose as say 'a drink with jam and bread' where many would select other than _tea_ given no cultural clueing from the musical domain.

Comment: Can you make  your question more clear? I have got a downvote, I am assuming I got that because the answer do not match the question. Put in a definition in this manner—"the requested phrase xxxx xxxx xxxx"—"definition"/"description"/"the meaning it should have" of the requested phrase( here you describe what you want from this phrase). e.g. "this phrase should have the meaning "catechism" and also should have riddle like quality" and then "koan" would have fit  the bill. As it is, it is unclear what you want the phrase to mean.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the closest example of that today would be mnemonics, or when teachers create songs for memorizing things such as the [50 states](http://www.mrsjonesroom.com/songs/50capitals.html), [Latin conjugations](https://www.nle.org/Portals/0/PDF/Mnemonics.pdf?ver=2018-07-23-093400-510) or [arithmetic order of operations](https://www.mnemonic-device.com/arithmetic/operations/).

Answer (score -1):

**Repartee** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repartee)) A swift, witty reply, especially one that is amusing. A conversation marked by a series of witty retorts. Skill in replying swiftly and wittily.

**Anaphora** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anaphora)) (rhetoric) The repetition of a phrase at the beginning of phrases, sentences, or verses, used for emphasis: (linguistics) An expression that can refer to virtually any referent, the specific referent being defined by context: (linguistics) An expression that refers to a preceding expression.

**Wordplay** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wordplay)) A humorous play on words; such plays on words collectively: A witty verbal exchange; such exchanges collectively.

**Riposte** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riposte)) To respond quickly; particularly if the response is humorous.